# Chrome extension(Angularjs) to Gmail Add-on (Appscript)

Tags: angularjs, google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension

We've developed a google chrome extension (with angularjs), which reads gmail mails, and sends them to on-premise servers by consuming a soap services. Now some of our customers have internal security policies prohibiting them to use chrome extensions, which now forces us to develop a Gmail Add-on (Google Appscript).

My question is, is there a way to comfortably reuse our angularjs application and include/use it in an Google Appscript application.

We are aware of the fact, that Appscript application actually arent client-side applications (unlike chrome extensions), and that we probably have to rewrite large parts of our application, but we just don't want to miss any opportunity regarding reusing our angularjs code.

Also did any of you experience major limitations of Google Appscript when consuming soap services (actually this is the main functionality of our existing application)

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

[GMail Add-ons won't allow for that](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/guides/restrictions) but you might be able to leverage [Google Apps Script Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

Unfortunately, there is a bigger issue you'll have to take into account. Many of the scopes associated with the GMail API are now restricted under the new [User Data Policy](https://developers.google.com/terms/api-services-user-data-policy), where your application will need to be verified and possibly have to undergo a security assessment; which could cost you anywhere from US$15K - US$75K! Read the section titled "How will the security Assessment Work?" in the [OAuth Application Verification FAQ](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en&ref_topic=3473162) for details.

Comment: Thank you for your useful hints! Well but that means, our existing chrome extension (as well as a possible future Gmail-addon) would have to undergo such a security assessment in future(since almost all useful gmail api scopes require it). That's daunting, since actually we can't really afford that.

Comment: It's more than daunting! It's draconian! as they also state: " This fee may be required whether or not your app passes the assessment" Not many people can risk that kind of cash on an extension.